# What is the reason that FTD2XX functions do not work in VB.NET after Visual Studio update(?), is there possible fix?

Tags: vb.net, ftdi

I am developing an app in VB.NET (for a customer with hardware using FTDI USB serial chip. Communication uses FTD2XX library and the respective Nuget package (FTD2XX.Net v1.2.1). After some update of Visual Studio (probably update to 17.1, but I am not sure) all functions except a few stopped working. Current VS version is 17.1.1.
For instance, it is possible to obtain number of devices attached by the FTDI driver:

```vb
Friend Declare Function FT_CreateDeviceInfoList Lib "FTD2XX.DLL" (ByRef lngNumDevs As Integer) As Integer
...
Dim ftStatus As Integer
Dim numDevices As Integer
ftStatus = FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(numDevices)
```

In the above snippet ftStatus result = 0 (i.e. OK) and `numDevices` is set to 1 (correct).

Problem starts when I want to do something serious:

```vb
Friend Declare Function FT_GetComPortNumber Lib "FTD2XX.DLL" (ByVal lnghandle As Integer, ByRef lplComPortNumber As Integer) As Integer
Friend Declare Function FT_Open Lib "FTD2XX.DLL" (ByVal iDevice As Integer, ByRef lnghandle As Integer) As Integer
Friend Declare Function FT_Close Lib "FTD2XX.DLL" (ByVal lnghandle As Integer) As Integer
Dim portHandle as Integer
Dim cpNumber as Long
For i% = 0 To 255
   ftStatus = FT_Open(i, portHandle)
   If ftStatus = FT_OK Then
      ftStatus = FT_GetComPortNumber(portHandle, cpNumber)
      ftStatus = FT_Close(portHandle)
      ' here is some non-essential code registering that port at index i% exists...
   End If
Next
```

In the above code, FT_Open returns `ftStatus = 0` (FT_OK) and sets a value for `portHandle`.

However, the next call, `FT_GetComPortNumber`, returns `ftStatus = 1` (FT_INVALID_HANDLE) and the value passed to `cpNumber` is 0xFFFF (shows as positive, but in fact should be -1, I guess...). What is worse, `FT_Close()` also returns `FT_INVALID_HANDLE` and the port remains open. I verified it by trying to open the port from another app - access denied.

Sometimes it seems that `FT_Write` and `FT_Read` functions work despite this mess, but in my last try I could not any communication with the hardware at all.

I tried to use `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` as possible workaround but that does not work at all. On top of that, I need to use bit-bang on RTS, because it controls supply voltage and reset of the hardware connected to the other side of the FTDI chip. Without possibility to bring RTS down for hundreds of milliseconds and then hold it up all the time I cannot control the hardware. AFAIK `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` provides no possibility to do that.

What could be the solution?

Comment: After update to VS 17.1.6 still no change.

Comment: How could I debug what is happening inside the library call? E.g. to see the stack frame, the actual parameters passed to the library function call, ... I can't believe that such a simple interface would suddenly stop working without any reason.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project just to test calls to FTD2XX.DLL? It can happen that a project goes bad and starts misbehaving.

Comment: Yes, I did (with no success). In the end the problem was in VS compiler settings, which were either changed, or the default value became interpreted differently than before, after the new update was installed. See my answer for detailed explanation.

Comment: The declarations are wrong, it must be `lnghandle As IntPtr`.  The difference between Integer and IntPtr matter when you run the app in 64-bit mode.  Prone to happen when targeting .NETCore, as likely in VS2022.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you! I used code written by someone else a long time ago, and FTDI documentation, too, is rather foggy.  So, instead of using ByRef lnghandle as Integer you suggest this? (It is a Visual Basic program, so not everything is under programmer's control as much as in C#, I suppose)
YES, this is the right answer. Would you mind posting it as answer to my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@HansPassant writes:

The declarations are wrong, it must be `lnghandle As IntPtr`. The difference between `Integer` and `IntPtr` matter when you run the app in 64-bit mode. Prone to happen when targeting .NETCore, as likely in VS2022.

-- Hans Passant

Comment: This is THE solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It works now. What I had to do was change the porthandle declaration to long.

`Dim portHandle As Long`

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, it appears to be a problem in compile configuration.
Open Solution properties Window and click on the Compile tab.

[image: Solution Properties, Compile tab]

Then click on "Advanced Compile Options"

[image: Advanced Compile Options - Integer Overflow Check]

If the "Remove integer overflow checks" checkbox is not checked, check it!

I have no idea how an integer overflow check can garble a 32-bit number not involved in any arithmetic operation whatsoever, but this is what really happened. I consider this a bug in Visual Basic compiler used in Visual Studio 17.1.6 (and a number of previous versions), but I did not dig deeper in this topic.

Comment: This is a workaround but not the real solution. Obviously you can switch your project to Traget CPU x86, forcing it to run as a 32 bit process. In this case your bug does not affect the handles which you have defined wrongly. But the correct solution is the answer from Hans Passant.

Answer (score -1):

For me this still does not work.

`

Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports

Module Module1

```
Private Declare Function FT_CreateDeviceInfoList Lib "FTD2XX.DLL" (ByRef lngNumDevs As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function FT_GetComPortNumber Lib "FTD2XX.DLL" (ByVal lnghandle As IntPtr, ByRef lplComPortNumber As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function FT_Open Lib "FTD2XX.DLL" (ByVal iDevice As Integer, ByRef lnghandle As IntPtr) As Integer
Private Declare Function FT_Close Lib "FTD2XX.DLL" (ByVal lnghandle As IntPtr) As Integer

Sub Main()
    Dim portHandle As Integer
    Dim cpNumber As Long

    Dim ftoStatus As Integer
    Dim ftcStatus As Integer
    Dim ftpStatus As Integer

    ftoStatus = FT_Open(0, portHandle)
    Console.WriteLine("FT_Open Status: " & ftoStatus)
    Console.WriteLine("PortHandle: " & portHandle)

    If ftoStatus = 0 Then
        ftpStatus = FT_GetComPortNumber(portHandle, cpNumber)
        Console.WriteLine("FT_GetComPortNumber Status: " & ftpStatus)
        Console.WriteLine("COM Port Number: " & cpNumber)
        ftcStatus = FT_Close(portHandle)
        Console.WriteLine("FT_Close Status: " & ftcStatus)
    End If

End Sub
```

End Module`

Comment: System.OverflowException
  HResult=0x80131516
  Nachricht = Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
  Quelle = System.Private.CoreLib
  This is the error i am getting: Stapelüberwachung:
   bei System.IntPtr.op_Explicit(IntPtr value)
   bei PSTester.Module1.Main() in C:\Users\bla\Desktop\ProjektEffTest\PS\PStester\PSTester\Form1.vb: Zeile21